# Adding image on keydown isn't working

Tags: jquery, html, image, position, keydown

BOMBERMAN GAME:
I am trying to add a bomb when I press keydown at the same position as "bomberman" (his position).

Adding an image on keydown isn't working. I'm not getting any errors in the console log.

```
function addBomb(lengte,hoogte){
         map.append('<div class="barrel" style="top: '+hoogte+'px; left: '+lengte+'px;"> </div>')
    };       
case 32: // drop bombs

var positionTop = $("#bomberman").position().top;
var positionLeft = $("#bomberman").position().left;
console.log($("#bomberman").position().top);

if (true){
    console.log('Testing console');

    addBomb(positionTop,positionLeft);

    countBombs += 1;

}   

             break;
```

Comment: There is no keydown code here. Maybe that's the problem :)

Comment: `keydown is'nt working`, what does it mean exactly?

Comment: @JeremyThille i edited the code and it still doesn't work

Comment: Is it normal that you define your function addBomb _after_ pressing a key? It sure won't work before. Besides, you define addBomb within a switch statement, that's certainly not the way to go. Move this function declaration outside of everything.

Comment: @JeremyThille i tried to move this function outside of everything but it is not working

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong passing the parameters.

Try with this:

```
function addBomb(hoogte, lengte){
         map.append('<div class="barrel" style="top: '+hoogte+'px; left: '+lengte+'px;"> </div>')
};
```

Comment: I changed the order of the parameters, he invokes `addBomb(positionTop,positionLeft)`

Comment: No, in your code positionTop will be the left of the "barrel", and positionLeft will be the top. That can be why it's not visible in the page.